# z-index not working in jquery data table

Tags: html, css

I am Unable to Display Action Box As a Upper Layer, I tried z-index too but no change.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                                
                                $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                                    "scrollX": true,
                                    "bSort": false,
                                    aLengthMenu: [
                                        [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                                        [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
                                    ],
                                    iDisplayLength: 10
                                });
                                
                            });
```

```css
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -160px;
  width: 160px;
  z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" style="z-index:1">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.No</th>
      <th>LeadCreated DateTime</th>
      <th>RetailerName</th>
      <th>ShopName</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Pincode</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2017</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>9904773479</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>304230</td>
      <td style="background: <?php if ($row->Status == 'InProcess') echo 'green';if ($row->Status == 'Closed') echo 'orange';if ($row->Status == 'Dead') echo 'black'; ?>;color: #FFFFFF">
        <?= $row->Status ?>
      </td>
      <td class="pbutton">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                                                Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                                            </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right " role="menu">
            <li><a href="#viewleadmodal" data-id="<?= $row->LeadId ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewleadmodal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>&nbsp;View</a></li>
            <li><a href="followup.php?LeadId=1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Add Lead Update</a></li>
            <li><a href="leadedit.php"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="check_perform_sdelete('14');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by visible as upper layer? if you can see it then it is visible?

Comment: Inspect and check if the z-index is above more than all other elements related.

Comment: It will not be able to overflow the `overflow` property rule declared on the containing parent, if that's what your hoping for - you would be required to take it completely out of the document flow with `position: fixed` in order for the "action box" to escape the hidden overflow - if that is even the intention, the question is not clear.

Comment: I can see the dropdown-menu when I click 'Action'. What do you mean by upper layer?

Comment: @ProEvilz: action box is open under datatable

Comment: @ Yasser Hussain: check in chrome browser

Comment: @JunedAnsari just try once with the highest value you can use with z-index. You will be sure then if it is not something else with bigger value

Comment: Yeah Overflow is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here **.dataTables_scrollBody** has overflow: auto. You have to remove it but after removing it, structure will destroy. So you have to call Action Box out side of table and then use the position in Action Box.
Actually overflow: auto is hiding Action Box which goes to outside of **.dataTables_scrollBody**.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one but I was still struggling with it. I added position-static to the dropdown div and that did the trick.

```
<div class="dropdown position-static">
```